# Accessing Controls of Partial view

Tags: view, controls, action, partial

In MVC5,

In `_LoginPartial`,

I would like to maintain some "hidden" controls those maintain the values required for the entire application in all other functionalities.

In Login - "form" - "submit" action method, how to access the controls in `_Loginpartial`?

Any example, please share.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you trying to have values stored on the login partial? I guess you could just put a div that's hidden? Why do you need this?

Comment: Yes, I store values in "_loginpartial" and am able to. Now i need those values inside "controller" "action", initiated from "login" view. This solution is default example solution of mvc5 where _Loginpartial always hangs at the top thru out the solution.

Comment: Lookup how to use the HTML forms, there should be a lot on this site. Look for keywords like HTML.beginform, you want to create actions in your controllers that accept values

Comment: I am looking for answer from somebody who may have already done this kind.